# Найти одно из совпадений в ElasticSearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Мне нужно найти есть совпадения по одному из значений с последующим выводом их в отдельные группы как при агрегации, то есть у меня например есть два значения ip и mac , хочу найти есть ли совпадения по этим значениям и если есть то по какому из них есть совпадение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может не совсем правильно но пока решил делать так. Пример в формате "Sense"

```
POST _search
{"size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "serial": "AAAAA"}},
        { "match": { "ip": "111.111.111.111"}},
        { "match": { "mac": "10:01:11:11:11:12"}}
      ]
    }
  },"aggs":{
    "serial" : {
      "filter":{
        "term": { "serial": "AAAAA"}
       }   
    }, "ip" : {
      "filter":{
        "term": { "ip": "111.111.111.111"}
       }   
    } , "mac" : {
      "filter":{
        "term": { "mac": "10:01:11:11:11:12"}
       }   
    }      
  }
 }
```